# Test agents pool in teamcity and distributing tests across the pool

Tags: teamcity, build-agent, distributed-testing

We are using Teamcity for CI and I am kind of new to Teamcity.

We have this problem.
We want to run specific set of test suite everyday at some time. But there are 1000s of tests. So we want to distribute the tests across multiple test machines and all are configured to Teamcity.

I was exploring and have this question.

1. Whether there is any way to create a pool of test machines?
2. Will Teamcity distribute tests across multiple test agents (build agent in Teamcity) on its own, once we trigger the build?

Comment: So you want to have one build configuration and when it runs it sends some tests to one agent and other tests to other agents, and then all the results are shown under a single build. Have I understood you correctly?

Comment: You need to split the tests up into parts so that you can create one build-configuration in TeamCity for each part, then you simply schedule all the build-configurations at the same time, they will be queued up in parallell on available build agents.

Comment: Depending on what kind of tests we're talking about here you might have help built into the test tools themselves, like category on NUnit unit-tests, this way you don't have to do much to the project containing the tests, simply tag tests with categories to split them up into sections, then create build-configurations that each test only one category.

Comment: Yes @Nanhydrin. You are perfectly right. Any way to achieve that?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen : Thanks for the input.we have kept splitting tests into parts as last option. Thing is we have to duplicate common path like login logout to each script. So if no better options available we may go for that.